# Double integral proof, where is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

The bounds are 0 < x < b , 0 < y < b.

$$ \int_0^b \int_0^b e^{-(x^{2}+y^{2})} dxdy $$ 
Since it is a square, x=y so we can write:

= $$ (\int_0^b e^{-(x^{2}+x^{2})} )^{2} dxdy $$
= $$ (\int_0^b e^{-(2x^{2})} )^{2} dxdy $$
= $$ (\int_0^b e^2e^{-x^{2}} )^{2} dxdy $$
= $$ e^{4} (\int_0^b e^{-x^{2}} )^{2} dxdy $$

I don't understand why $e^{4}$ is supposed to be just 4. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the first sentence.  Note the absolute values in the definition of $D$.  The area of your domain is four times what you thought it was.

So,

$$\iint_D \exp[-(x^2+y^2)] dx dy = \int_{-b}^b \exp(-x^2) dx \int_{-b}^b \exp(-y^2) dy \\ = 2 \int_{0}^b \exp(-x^2) dx \left(2\int_{0}^b \exp(-y^2) dy\right) = 4 \left( \int_{0}^b \exp(-x^2) dx \right)^2.$$

The step going from the first line to the second line is allowed because both functions are even functions:  $f(x) = f(-x).$

What you did replacing $y$ with $x$ in the second line of your solution isn't quite right.  That removes the dependence on $y$ in the exponential, which isn't correct.  The symmetry comes into play at the end; the only difference between the two integrals at the end of my solution is the variable.  The limits, and the form of the integrand, are the same.